# Tag wiki edit approved twice?

Tags: bug

The good news is my [tag wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/squarefree/info) edit (actually creating the wiki & excerpt for a new tag) was promptly approved.

However it seems to have been approved twice, crediting me with two +2s.

Is this right?  It seems overly generous (if not pedantic) to separately approve the new wiki and new excerpt, if that's what happened.

Not complaining, just didn't want a possible bug to go unreported.

Comment: It appears as two different reviews in the review queue. That is, one for the wiki, and one for the general info.

Comment: I recall this being discussed before on meta.

Comment: Don't look a gift horse in the mouth.